# ForeignKey attribute on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, ef-database-first

Let's suppose i've a class Auction

```
public class Auction {
[Key]
public int Id { get; set;}

public User Seller {get; set;}
public User Winner {get; set;}
}
```

and a class User

```
public class User {

[Key]
public string Username {get;set;}
public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

What can i do to make Seller and Winner as FK using ForeignKey attribute on Visual Studio?

**Edit**

I use the [key] attribute because i've got other tables in the db and their  PK is not called id, so i use in every class the attribute [key] to use the same style.

And when i try to upload a Seller of an Auction by using an already existing user it says

```
The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Seller' on type 'Database.Auction' is not valid. The foreign key name 'User' was not found on the dependent type 'Database.Auction'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.
```

It was for this reason i wanted to specify the FK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They already are FK in your `Auction` class. They will be mapped as FK. You might want to use lazy loading later on so:

```
public class Auction {
   public int Id { get; set;}

   public virtual User Seller {get; set;}
   public virtual User Winner {get; set;}
}
```

Also you don't need the `[Key]` annotation above property called `Id`.

**Update after question was edited:**

You might need to enable migrations. Go to the Package Manager Console, if it is not  open you can open it via menu View at the menu bar of the Visual Studio.

Then write in it `enable-migrations` enter, then set `AutomaticMigrations` in the generated class to `true`, then again in Package Manager console write `update-database`, run your application.

**Foot notes:**

You didn't state what kind of app your are creating but usually keeping user password is a bad idea. You usually suppose to keep hashed version of it.

Comment: @Sanci Did you enabled migrations and updated your database? Is this is console or ASP.NET-MVC app?

Comment: I must admit i am ignorant in this area. I'm writing it on visual studio 2013 and SQL Server 2012. I don't know how to enable migrations

Comment: @Sanci Ok what is the kind of application you are writing? In other words when you started a new Solutrion what did you choose? See my update in a minute or two.

Comment: Yes thanks, sorry if i'm late but i came back home from work just now.